# How can I draw a projectile arc on turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, python-3.9

I need help with learning how to draw a arc in turtle graphics. I would prefer a simple set of code that I can easily incorporate into my pre-existing code.

I've tried to make an arc following online instructions but its not projectile, its more like a smiley face arc would be.

Comment: This question is not a good one according to the [How to Ask Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question doesn't point a particular issue you encounter. You want someone to do your work in your stead: "I would prefer a simple set of code that I can easily incorporate into my pre-existing code." You should post the issue you are facing (not just "I can't do it"), the code you tried, and explanations of your reasoning for this code.

Answer (score 1):

This code keeps track of two variables, one called `x_velocity`, and the other called `y_velocity`. These variables represent the speed that the projectile is moving in x and y directions respectively. It then loops through a couple times, moving the turtle at those velocities and then applying gravity to the `y_velocity`.

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(3) # 1:slowest, 3:slow, 5:normal, 10:fast, 0:fastest

x_velocity = 4
y_velocity = 20

for i in range(50):
  # apply velocity to the turtle, move it
  t.goto(t.xcor() + x_velocity, t.ycor() + y_velocity)
  # apply gravity to the projectile
  y_velocity -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but for my code the user chooses the angle (degrees) and the velocity the arch is at.

Comment: @Polly, your question has been answered. You should be able to figure out how to convert velocity and angle into x/y velocities. Stack Overflow users are not here to do your work in your place.